# My very own .exe file doesn't work matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, exe

I am using matlab R2011b. I created a matlab gui that is a simple calculator just make addition. Then I created an .exe file. When I doudle click the .exe file which is in 'distrib' folder, nothing happens. Also, there is no error message.

I don't understand the reason. Is there anybody who has an idea about it?

Comment: List the complete steps that you performed from start to finish to create the executable.  There are a various amount of things that could go wrong and that may be why it doesn't work.  Also, are you sure MATLAB Runtime is installed?  http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/

Comment: As rayryeng asked, I would like to know what process you followed to create the .exe file. It's likely that that's where the problem is.

Comment: @rayryeng I don't know MATLAB Runtime is installed or not. How can I check this?

Comment: @Trogdor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke599czEmxU I watched this video to create the .exe file

Comment: @rayryeng the MCR is always installed automatically when Matlab is installed. Look in the section [Installing the MCR and MATLAB on the Same Machine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/working-with-the-mcr.html)

Comment: Run the executable from the system console and post the output here.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered 2 problems in the past when I tried to create an exe.

A. The program shut itself down as soon as it was 'finished'. To check whether the program actually runs, consider making a test program like this:

```
'abcd'
pause(5)
'efg'
```

If you can make a program like this, at least you know you can make a working exe.

B. You can choose from a few kinds of projects. Several of these make an exe, but you only want 1 of them. Not sure which one but it is not that hard to try all 3 or so options with a simple test program.